# Generating Unique ID for same group

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have data set,

```
CustID  Rating
1   A
1   A
1   B
2   A
2   B
2   C
2   D
3   X
3   X
3   Z
4   Y
4   Y
5   M
6   N
7   O
8   U
8   T
8   U
```

And expecting Output

```
CustID  Rating  ID
1   A   1
1   A   1
1   B   1
2   A   1
2   B   2
2   C   3
2   D   4
3   X   1
3   X   1
3   Z   2
4   Y   1
4   Y   1
5   M   1
6   N   1
7   O   1
8   U   1
8   T   2
8   U   1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? you can add that code and ask what is not working and what you are expecting, SO is not for helping you to write code for you. You have to try first.

Comment: Do you need the ID to be unique for each rating or for each rating within each customer? E.g. if you had `CustomerID = 4` and `Rating = B`, what would you expect for `Id`?

Comment: Here the ID would be 1. I want to know, whether the same customer has assigned multiple ratings or not.

Comment: @Chetan doesn't the answer provided solve your problem?

Comment: It's not giving the desired output....I am trying...Using First. and Last.

Comment: @Chetan, could you please point out to me how the output provided by you is different from the one in the answer? Or perhaps you haven't described your problem well enough?

Comment: Its producing missing values for column ID

Comment: Should the output row `1 B 1` be `1 B 2`. If not, would you please explain why it should be as you have shown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, I selected the distinct possible ratings into a macro variable to be used in an array statement. These distinct values are then searched in the ratings tolumn to return the number assigned at each successful find.

You can avoid the macro statement in this case by replacing the `%sysfunc` by 3 (the number of distinct ratings, if you know it before hand). But the `%sysfunc` statement helps resolve this in case you don't know.

```
data have;
  input CustomerID    Rating $;
  cards;
  1           A       
  1           A       
  1           B       
  2           A       
  2           A       
  3           A       
  3           A       
  3           B       
  3           C     
  ;
run; 

proc sql noprint;
 select distinct quote(strip(rating)) into :list separated by ' '
 from have
 order by 1;
 %put &list.;
quit;
```

If you know the number before hand:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array num(3) $ _temporary_ (&list.);
  do i = 1 to dim(num);
    if findw(rating,num(i),'tips')>0 then id = i;
  end;
    drop i;
 run;
```

Otherwise:

```
%macro Y;
data want;
  set have;
  array num(%sysfunc(countw(&list., %str( )))) $ _temporary_ (&list.);
  do i = 1 to dim(num);
    if findw(rating,num(i),'tips')>0 then id = i;
  end;
    drop i;
 run; 
%mend;
%Y;
```

The output:

```
Obs CustomerID Rating id 
1    1          A      1 
2    1          A      1 
3    1          B      2 
4    2          A      1 
5    2          A      1 
6    3          A      1 
7    3          A      1 
8    3          B      2 
9    3          C      3
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working....There are two angle to it..one is customerId and second Rating...I want to know for each customer there should be only one rating...If the same rating is repeated for same CustomerID....then it should assign value 1

Comment: How's this reflected in your desired output which you provided in the question? And where does column ID appear in your question?

Comment: Id is the calculated column.If i add more ratings it does not work.

Comment: I have updated the questions with some additional data points

Comment: Your updated question is completely different from your initial question. And you have not explained the logic behind your new question. It's hard to help you if you can't even describe your own problem. I am busy trying to solve mine..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is sorted by customerid and rating (as in the original unedited question). Is the following what you want:

```
data want;
   set have;
   by customerid rating;

   if first.customerid then
      id = 0;

   if first.rating then
      id + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. If it is working fine then 3 points: 1) Please mark the answer correct; 2) Fix the output in your question to match what you require, e.g. `1 B 1` should be `1 B 2`; 3) As you will see from all of the comments, your question did not have enough information in it, so a more detailed description of the logic required would have meant you could have got an answer sooner, e.g. "Within each `customerid` group increment `id` for each unique value of `rating`" might have helped. I originally had another solution because I thought you wanted something different.